# ADODB::_RecordsetPtr::Open throws Exception like Query timeout Expired in c++

Tags: c++, sql, adodb

here i am trying to query a table of sql server 2008 r2 from my c++ application. It contains 21,54,514. but it throws an exception like "Query timeout expired" . below is my code base

```
ADODB::_ConnectionPtr           m_pDBConnection;
ADODB::_RecordsetPtr                m_pRS;

m_pDBConnection.CreateInstance("ADODB.Connection");
m_pRS.CreateInstance("ADODB.RecordSet");

m_pRS->Open(wstrSQL.c_str(), _variant_t((IDispatch *) m_pDBConnection, true),
        ADODB::adOpenStatic,
        ADODB::adLockReadOnly,
        ADODB::adCmdText);
```

When the above line is get executed it throws the above said exception.

i know the issue , the issue is actually with  default timeout set. it is actually 15 sec.

can anybody please tell how to reset or change timeout in **ADODB::_RecordsetPtr**. I searched in google a lot , we can do reset timeout for **ADODB::_ConnectionPtr** but not for **ADODB::_RecordsetPtr**. it would be vary usefull for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Coding Journey](http://codingjourney.blogspot.de/2008/11/ado-connection-timeout-command-or.html) you need to set the [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678265(v=vs.85).aspx) on the connection **and** on the command.

```
// The recordset for the result
ADODB::_RecordsetPtr rs;
// Timeout on connection
m_pDBConnection->CommandTimeout = 60;
// Need to create command first, then configure it, then open RecordSet
ADODB::_CommandPtr cmd(__uuidof(ADODB::Command));
cmd->ActiveConnection = m_pDBConnection;
cmd->CommandText = wstrSQL.c_str();
cmd->CommandTimeout = 60;
rs->Open(cmd, vtMissing, ADODB::adOpenStatic, ADODB::adLockReadOnly, ADODB::adCmdText);
// Reset the timeout on the connection
m_pDBConnection->CommandTimeout = 15;
```

Comment: @user1450931 If my answer helped you please accept it and maybe even upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @WernerHenze. I used this for vba, not c++, but I had not seen any vba questions that rolled all of the needed properties (connection, query, timeout) into one command and then executed it against a recordset. That helped me!

Comment: I like this, but can you really pass cmd as the first parameter to the Open call?  Won't compile for me.  Instead of `rs->Open` I would try `cmd->Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdStoredProc)` which should return that `_RecordsetPtr` object

Comment: @demongolem The code compiles and works for me. Regarding Open see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx.